# How to select two different collections of data in GraphQL in a single query

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I am building a blog but with some snippets functionality that is setup as an additional collection. I want to feature both the latest blog posts as well as the latest snippets on a single page.

I am editing the code and I see the following graphql query:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {  
    allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
      filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "blog-post" } }}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            templateKey
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  '
```

Can I just add another "query" here such as:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query IndexQuery {  
  allMarkdownRemark(
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
      filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "blog-post" } }}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            templateKey
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    },  
allSnippetPosts(
      sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] },
      filter: { frontmatter: { templateKey: { eq: "snippet-post" } }}
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          excerpt(pruneLength: 400)
          id
          fields {
            slug
          }
          frontmatter {
            title
            templateKey
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
          }
        }
      }
    }
  '
```

I have all the backend stuff done, just need help with the graphql part here.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can. You're missing a `}` at the end of the query.